# Understanding compiled regex in .net

Tags: .net, regex

I have a regex that will be used repetitively where the stringLiteral will vary from one invocation to the next.

One being:

```
.*(^stringLiteral Number 1\r?\n)([\w|\s][^\r\n]+)(.+)
```

and the next being:

```
.*(^stringLiteral Number 2\r?\n)([\w|\s][^\r\n]+)(.+)
```

Is there a chance for optimization here?

EDIT: To be a bit more explicit about the live data I'm working against - I'm parsing the body an email that contains name/value pairs. I know the names (labels) and i know that the value i'm after is the line that follows the label. But I can't be sure that the name/value pairs (lines) will always fall in the same order - so I can't build one large expression.

I have to build multiple expressions the discard everything from the beginning of the block to and including the given label (this would be the stringLiteral); capture the next line into a capture group; then discard everything following that line.

so this line capture the Name field

```
myOrder.Name = Regex.Replace(resultString, @".*(^Name\r\n)([\w|\s][^\r\n]+)(.+)", "$2", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

and this line captures the price field

```
myOrder.Price= Regex.Replace(resultString, @".*(^Price\r\n)([\w|\s][^\r\n]+)(.+)", "$2", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: Why not precompile both? I'm not a fan of putting logic inside data - you must think whether these are two expressions which happen to coincide in much, or a single expression with a variable part.

Comment: Where do I go to learn about 'pre-compiling'? thx

Comment: I meant simply instantiating each regex only once, using `new Regex(...pattern...)`. That's the single great optimisation to do. But there's the possibility of really 'compling' expressions into machine code, but only if utmost performance is key (<http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Regular_Expression_Recipes—Compiling_Regular_Expressions>).

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could condense them into a single expression if you want to:

> `.(^stringLiteral Number [12]\r?\n)([\w|\s][^\r\n]+)(.+)`

If you post an example of the input you want to match or capture I could probably help some more.

Answer (score 0):

You can condense them into a single expression as suggested by Andrew.

You should also disable backtracking where it's not needed, e.g.: (?:subregexp) instead of (subregexp). Doing so saves memory.